# Using base64 image strings for an app in React Native crashes

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am using base64 strings as image sources. when i open my app crashes immediately when loading any image with font. and at the same time the application closes me. this happens only on IOS on Android everything works fine.

I am using react-native version: "0.62.2"

For example:

```js
<ImageBackground source={{"uri": 'base64encodedstring'}} />
```

Comment: Please read [Is English required on stack overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)  (tl;dr: yes). Other language versions of SO are available. Note to other SO users: [Do not translate this on behalf of the OP, if they can't ask the question in English, then they will struggle to respond to comments and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/19068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Using base64 strings for an Image URI crashes app](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28583#issuecomment-614239427) issue on GitHub:

> For anyone else that comes across this just change the version of Flipper in the podfile to
>
> ```
> versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.37.0'
> ```
>
> as this is what the pr did

So, for this case:

```
 versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.37.0'
 versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.2'
 versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.1'
```

Comment: Remember to run `cd ios && pod install`